# Can we encrypt data that must be decrypted with any private key plus a server generate bits?

Tags: security, encryption, private-key

I have come up with a scenario to make a secure data. Suppose I have a public encrypted file that anybody can download. But whenever anyone want to decrypt that data they need to get a key from server

To make the key cannot be shared. The key from server will not be able to decrypt the data directly. But the data **must be** decrypted with the **client's private key** after, without server knowing those client's privateKey

I hope below diagram could explain it clearly

[image]

Is it possible? What is the algorithm that could do this?

Comment: I don't really get purpose of the "double encryption" and what do you want to achieve. You want to make sure that the original file can be decrypted only by a specific client? (having its private key?)

Comment: Security protocol design questions are really not on-topic on stackoverflow. You might want to look up hybrid encryption and compare and contrast your design with it.

Comment: @gusto2 Yes, what I want is, the original file can be decrypted only by a specific client, using their own private key, without the need to re-encrypt the original file, just have the server send another key unique to for each user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have come up with a scenario to make a secure data. Suppose I have a public encrypted
> file that anybody can download. But whenever anyone want to decrypt that data they need to get a key from server
>
> To make the key cannot be shared. The key from server will not be able to decrypt the
> data directly. But the data must be decrypted with the client's
> private key after, without server knowing those client's privateKey

Make it so **each time the file is downloaded, a random string is appended**. The file is then encrypted with the user's **public** key, and symmetrically with an appropriate hash generated by that same string. For example a GPG file inside a password-protected ZIP file.

So Alice downloads `Financial_Report_201809_d8a1b2e6.pdf.zip` while Bob downloads `Financial_Report_201809_ff2a91c3.pdf.zip`.

If they want to decrypt the file, they need to send the server back the random string, and the server will supply them with the password for the outer ZIP. Then they're left with an encrypted file that only their private key can decode.

Note that **once they have decrypted the file**, nothing stops them from forwarding the file in the clear to someone else. On the other hand, sharing the encrypted PDF avails them nothing, as they would also need to share their private key.

Also note that since they need to be online to get the outer password, and they're left with a cleartext file at the end, **this is (almost) functionally equivalent to the file being downloaded in the clear once user identity has been established**.

The main differences are:

- the ciphered file (PDF in the above example) might not have been encrypted by the server at all. It might have been supplied by the user, who is then satisfied that only he can read the file back (it makes little sense for anyone else to download it, though).
- the transmitted file is *very* securely transmitted. An attacker with full access to the datastream would not be able to decode the file (but this is no more than could be gained by just encrypting with the user's public key - no extra ZIP stage required).

## UPDATE

You want to encrypt the whole file *only once* (for all users), and then send the same file to Alice and Bob, and have them require *two different keys* at decryption time. The problem here is that Alice's key will also work on Bob's file, since **it is the same file**. There's no magic that's going to work here, unless you can hide some detail of the decryption process (e.g. use a program that you control and that can't be debugged and that will always connect to your server: a proposition that has **consistently shown to be losing**).

If you want to **limit** the encryption cost, you can send the massive file with both a symmetrically encrypted data payload (always the same) and a very short, asymmetrically encrypted key payload (always different), but **still** you will be vulnerable to the decrypted key being captured:

```
[ RSA(ALICE.PUB, "SQUEAMISH OSSIFRAGE" ][ RIJNDAEL("SQUEAMISH OSSIFRAGE", LARGE FILE) ]
```

In the above scenario some program has to read the encryption header and decrypt the 'Squeamish Ossifrage' password, then go on decrypting (e.g. playing) the extra payload without the password being intercepted. This means that you need to supply the program yourself.

This is functionally equivalent to the program connecting to the server and downloading a "yes" or "no" to the question (appropriately encrypted, signed and secured) *"I am Alice's player. Can I decrypt and play 'Never Wanna Give You Up.avi'?"* , with no passwords or public keys being known or exchanged apart from the secret shared by Alice's player and the server.

## UPDATE II

If the goal is to save encryption resources, the encryption could be made client side as hinted in the comment:

- the file is encrypted the once, with a purpose-generated private key.
- the private key is stored inside a binary (we must assume it to be unhackable).
- the user has to supply his public key for the decryption to work
- the program can verify the public key from a repository (or, alternately, the user can supply the public key to the server, which will generate and send the binary file for download)
- the program then runs both the decryption and reencryption
- the user is left with a file encrypted with his public key, that he alone can decrypt.

## UPDATE III

In order for the cleartext file to never be exposed (i.e., it does not matter whether the algorithm gets leaked), you could devise the following scheme. Keep in mind that I'm not a cryptographer and there could be all sort of side channels left uncovered.

- You prepare a conversion table that maps each 16-bit word into another 16-bit word. This is a flavour of symmetrical encryption, even if you use two reciprocal matrices for encoding and decoding. Each matrix holds all possible 16-bit words, which means 65536 values, and is therefore 128 Kb in size.
- You encrypt the file, once, with the encryption matrix. Without the decryption matrix, the file is unusable.
- The user has to send you his public key.
- You prepare a transmogrification matrix by encrypting each word with that key, and use the decryption value as an index.

So, for example, say the first word of the cleartext file is A18B. In the encryption matrix, after the scramble, the A18B-th position will contain say 701C, and the decryption matrix, therefore, in the 701Cth position, will hold a18b.

The user has a file starting with 701c... which is of no use.

The user sends you his public key and you run 65536 encryptions on all words from 0000 to ffff. You then determine that the encryption of a18b is 791c. You prepare a re-encoding matrix that has 791c in the 701cth position.

You then send the user this matrix, which has 128K bytes, where the 701cth position is 791c.

The user runs the transmogrification, which is very fast, and is left with a file starting with 791c (as the 701c became 791c - I mistakenly chose two similar values in my example, that is of no significance). This value, *once decrypted with his private key*, will yield a18b which is the "readable" value.

The user has now a file that's been encrypted by his public key. The a18b value never appeared anywhere.

All that's left is for the user to decrypt the file using his private key and a code block size of 16 bits. *This operation will be run by the client and be quite slow*, and it's the reason why usually a large random quick symmetric key is RSA-encoded, and used to symmetrically quickly encrypt the large file, which can be quickly decrypted after the private key has unlocked the symmetric key.

The user cannot send the 128K to anyone, for they're useless without the private key.

(The problem here is still that the user can now decrypt the file with his private key, and send it around, even if it's unwieldy as it's a very large file).

Comment: I think it could be possible that, I could send a magic key that will magically transform "my special algorithm's encrypted file" into "client's public key encrypted file" if I could determine the client's public key. Actually the process is client must request a key from my server with their public key. After the client got the key, the client could run my special transform algorithm with the key I sent but the result will only match with his private key, something like that

Comment: Yes, that's doable. Updating answer

Comment: Well, not just that, instead of just using a program that can't be debugged, I expect that it should have math algorithm that could do the job in the cryptographic ways, even the algorithm are expose, it could not be run in reverses and extract the information

Comment: Suppose there was a "255" data that, when encrypted with alice public key, it will become "25" but with bob key it will become "20". But I just host my encrypted data "100". When bob send his private key to me, I could just try to encrypted the original data with his key (get "20") and compare to my hosted data ("100"), So I told him that he could divide my encrypted data ("100") by 5 (to get "20"), and when alive ask server will tell her to divide by 4. The algorithm I expect is not just divide but would be cryptographically more complicate

Comment: It is doable, but requires RSA encryption to be used on the whole target file. This will be costly on the client.

Comment: Thanks for your solution I will try to deeply think about it. But your concern is already within my speculation, my approach is useful in some situation and don't mind if someone try to share the raw file, because it would be more disadvantage than getting the official file from me

Answer (score 0):

> the data must be decrypted with the client's private key after, without server knowing those client's privateKey 
>   the original file can be decrypted only by a specific client, using their own private key,

There's a commonly used cryptosystem called [hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

The steps are:

1. The original data are encrypted with a random unique key.
2. The data encryption key is encrypted by a client's public key (the client's public key needs to be know to the server).
3. The client needs to use its private key to decrypt the file encryption key and decrypt the file

Comment: The problem of this approach is, after client decrypt that random key, they can share that key to anyone after and now the encryption key itself now exposed. Which I try to make it not happen

Comment: To put it simply, I try to make DRM system. I could sell the key to access the encrypted files but the client cannot share that key to anyone except also sharing their own private key, which will make them at risk

Comment: @Thaina You could specify it upfront. See how other online media services work. Usually the content is (pre)encrypted by client's key as the user downloads the content (yes, that approach requires exposing a running streaming service, not just storing an encrypted file). And that doesn't prevent the user sharing the content itself.

Comment: Surely we can't avoid user sharing the decrypted original file. It can't by any mean anyway. But I try to make a system that, I could host the encrypted file that anyone could download (so it could be CDN) and it will be more practical to download that file from my host and buy the key than download that file from anyone else. And so trying to encrypt each file when downloading is not practical

Answer (score -1):

you can use any asymmetric cryptography algorithms.

A **public** and a **private** **key pairs** are used. The public key is used to encrypt data that can only be decrypted with the private key.  There are a lot of resources on this, for example the article form [InfoSec Institute](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/review-asymmetric-cryptography/).

There are several proven good asymmetric algorithms such as RSA, DSA, Elliptic Curve Crytography (used by Ethereum blockchain). There are many Python libraries too.